# Pigeonhole Principle: Diameter Problem

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Let  a circumference $K$ and $200$ points on $K$. Each point is at the end of a diameter corresponding to an integer number of degrees. Prove there are at least two points that are different ends of the same diameter.

---

There are $200$ points  (pigeons $n=200$) and $180$ diameters  (holes $m=180)$ :

$200/180 \approx 1.1 \therefore $ by the PHP there will be at least two points that are different ends of the same diameter

**Is my proof correct? Is there another formal way to prove it?**

Comment: Just to be clear.  You are saying there are 180 *potential* diameters (a diameter goes from $k^{\circ}$ to $(k + 180^{\circ})$ fro $0 \le k < 180$).  So there are 200 > 180 (not sure why you need 200/180 > 1 when 200 > 180 will suffice) holes.  They can't all be on different diameters.  Yes, you argument is good.

Comment: You don't need an overly complicated or formal proof. All you need to say is that there are only $180$ diameters so the first $180$ points can be assigned to unique diameters. Then, the next $20$ points will have to be on diameters with a point already on them. You don't need to calculate $200/180$.